# How to pass file to qnx using putty

Tags: file, putty, qnx

How can I pass file to qnx using putty?? I tried to connect using root@theipaddress but it always returning connection refuse what might be the problem?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Once there, please share you complete command-line as well as PuTTY's even log.

Answer (score 0):

If root doesn't have a password, you can try to set a password. At least, it is required for FTP connections.